# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method sometimes not called

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have two iPad mini (ios8.3, and ios9.1) and one iPad mini 2.

- on iPad mini 2 (ios.9.1): works well.
- on iPad mini (ios.8.3): **sometime** the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called
- on iPad mini (ios.9.1): **sometime** the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called

I am working on XCode7.2, Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter which device it is.
Are you using different calls for iOS8 and 9?

Where in the app are you making the register calls? The usual procedure is making the calls at app startup.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    //iOS 9
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
else
{
    //iOS < 9
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
}
```